# libcurl crashes in a Windows service

Tags: c++, curl, winapi, windows-services, libcurl

My service receives data from some processes, parses it, and sends an HTTP post to my PHP server.

When I started writing the code, it was an ordinary 64-bit program. After I finished, I converted it to a service, but some crashes happen when the service tries to send the data.

The reason isn't clear, as I use libcurl in other places in the service without problems.

My receiver is something like this:

```
while (true)
{
    memset(pipe_buffer, 0, 10000);
    cres = ReadFile(pipe, pipe_buffer, 10000, &read, 0);
    ofile << "[*] got a packet with length : " << read << endl;
    if (read > 0 && cres) {
        ofile << "[*] " << pipe_buffer << endl;

        // send the request
        string payload;
        payload += "data=";
        payload += pipe_buffer;
        ofile << "[*] sending post : " << url << "?" << payload<< endl;
        CURL *curl;
        curl = curl_easy_init();
        if (!curl) {
            ofile << "[!] curl failed to init" << endl;
            return 0;
        }
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, url.c_str()); // crashes start here
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, payload.c_str());
        curl_easy_perform(curl);
        curl_easy_cleanup(curl);
    }
    else {
         // the client may dissconnect , wait for it to connect again
         DisconnectNamedPipe(pipe); ConnectNamedPipe(pipe, 0);
    }
}
```

I'm getting very different and strange errors every time.

Most of them come from `RtlFreeHeap()` that libcurl calls, and integer divided by zero from some WSA functions that `curl_easy_perform()` uses.

The crash may occur in any of the libcurl functions, starting from `curl_easy_setopt()`.

The same code works without problems in an ordinary program.

EDIT : after digging this is the function causes corruption
the reason why the crash didn't happen for previous curl usage is that I don't use this function except after this , then I create a receiver thread that works in parallel with a thread that uses this function , also the ordinary program didn't crash as this function was only for the service (a program not running in local system can use EnumWindows) 
I think Poco net didn't crash as it's based on c++ not c and uses new/delete to allocate and free the memory but the crash coming from curl and other functions start from _malloc_base and similar c allocation functions

the function code :

```
wstring GetCommandLineRemote(DWORD id) {
  PROCESS_BASIC_INFORMATION pbInfo = { 0 };
  HANDLE hProc = OpenProcess(PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS, 0, id);
  if (!hProc || hProc == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE) return wstring(L"");
  auto status = fNtQueryInformationProcess(hProc, ProcessBasicInformation, &pbInfo, sizeof(pbInfo), NULL);
  if (!NT_SUCCESS(status)) { CloseHandle(hProc); return wstring(L""); }
  BPEB bbeb = { 0 };
  BOOL result;
  result = ReadProcessMemory(hProc, (void*)pbInfo.PebBaseAddress, &bbeb, sizeof(BPEB), 0);
  if (!result) { CloseHandle(hProc); return wstring(L""); }
  BRTL_USER_PROCESS_PARAMETERS parameters = { 0 };
  result = ReadProcessMemory(hProc, (void*)((uintptr_t)bbeb.ProcessParameters), &parameters, sizeof(BRTL_USER_PROCESS_PARAMETERS), 0);
  if (!result) { CloseHandle(hProc); return wstring(L""); }
  UNICODE_STRING CommandLine = { 0 };
  CommandLine.Length = parameters.CommandLine.Length;
  CommandLine.MaximumLength = parameters.CommandLine.MaximumLength;
  CommandLine.Buffer = new WCHAR[CommandLine.MaximumLength];
  result = ReadProcessMemory(hProc, (void*)parameters.CommandLine.Buffer, CommandLine.Buffer, parameters.MaximumLength, 0);
  if (!result) { CloseHandle(hProc); return wstring(L""); }
  CloseHandle(hProc);
  wstring wCommandLine = CommandLine.Buffer;
  delete CommandLine.Buffer;
  return wCommandLine;
}
```

I'm using this function to distinguish the instances of my helper process by the command line that the process started with

so the mechanism to find the instance looks like this :

```
vector<DWORD> enum_ids(wstring proc_name) {
  HANDLE snap = CreateToolhelp32Snapshot(TH32CS_SNAPPROCESS, 0);
  vector<DWORD> ids;
  PROCESSENTRY32W entry = { 0 };
  entry.dwSize = sizeof(entry);
  if (!Process32FirstW(snap, &entry)) return ids;
  do {
      wstring p_name = entry.szExeFile;
      auto check_pos = p_name.find(proc_name);
      if (check_pos != wstring::npos) {
        ofile << "[*] found process instance with id : " << entry.th32ProcessID << endl;
        ids.push_back(entry.th32ProcessID);
      }
  } while (Process32NextW(snap, &entry));
  return ids;
}


DWORD find_process(wstring proc_name,wstring unique) {
  DWORD process_id = 0;
  auto ids = enum_ids(proc_name);
  for (auto id : ids) {
      wstring wCommandLine = GetCommandLineRemote(id);
      auto check_pos = wCommandLine.find(unique);
      if (check_pos != wstring::npos) {
          process_id = id;
          break;
      }
      //if (id == 83004) { process_id = id; break; } 83004 is example , if I used this instead of the above comparison code no errors occur so I assumed the errors come from GetCommandLineRemote 
  }
  return process_id;
}
```

then in the service main thread :

```
CreateThread(0, 0, recieve, 0, 0, 0);
CreateThread(0, 0, FindParticularInstance, (char*)"ch", 0, 0);
```

now after finding the errors source , how this function do all these errors and how to prevent it from this ?

the definitions of the structures (from NiroSoft and process hacker) :

```
 typedef struct _CURDIR
{
  UNICODE_STRING DosPath;
  PVOID Handle;
} CURDIR, *PCURDIR;

typedef struct _RTL_DRIVE_LETTER_CURDIR
{
  WORD Flags;
  WORD Length;
  ULONG TimeStamp;
  STRING DosPath;
} RTL_DRIVE_LETTER_CURDIR, *PRTL_DRIVE_LETTER_CURDIR;

typedef struct _BRTL_USER_PROCESS_PARAMETERS
{
  ULONG MaximumLength;
  ULONG Length;
  ULONG Flags;
  ULONG DebugFlags;
  PVOID ConsoleHandle;
  ULONG ConsoleFlags;
  PVOID StandardInput;
  PVOID StandardOutput;
  PVOID StandardError;
  CURDIR CurrentDirectory;
  UNICODE_STRING DllPath;
  UNICODE_STRING ImagePathName;
  UNICODE_STRING CommandLine;
  PVOID Environment;
  ULONG StartingX;
  ULONG StartingY;
  ULONG CountX;
  ULONG CountY;
  ULONG CountCharsX;
  ULONG CountCharsY;
  ULONG FillAttribute;
  ULONG WindowFlags;
  ULONG ShowWindowFlags;
  UNICODE_STRING WindowTitle;
  UNICODE_STRING DesktopInfo;
  UNICODE_STRING ShellInfo;
  UNICODE_STRING RuntimeData;
  RTL_DRIVE_LETTER_CURDIR CurrentDirectores[32];
  ULONG EnvironmentSize;
} BRTL_USER_PROCESS_PARAMETERS, *PBRTL_USER_PROCESS_PARAMETERS;

typedef struct _BPEB
{
  UCHAR InheritedAddressSpace;
  UCHAR ReadImageFileExecOptions;
  UCHAR BeingDebugged;
  UCHAR BitField;
  ULONG ImageUsesLargePages : 1;
  ULONG IsProtectedProcess : 1;
  ULONG IsLegacyProcess : 1;
  ULONG IsImageDynamicallyRelocated : 1;
  ULONG SpareBits : 4;
  PVOID Mutant;
  PVOID ImageBaseAddress;
  PPEB_LDR_DATA Ldr;
  PBRTL_USER_PROCESS_PARAMETERS ProcessParameters;
  PVOID SubSystemData;
  PVOID ProcessHeap;
  PRTL_CRITICAL_SECTION FastPebLock;
  PVOID AtlThunkSListPtr;
  PVOID IFEOKey;
  ULONG CrossProcessFlags;
  ULONG ProcessInJob : 1;
  ULONG ProcessInitializing : 1;
  ULONG ReservedBits0 : 30;
  union
  {
      PVOID KernelCallbackTable;
      PVOID UserSharedInfoPtr;
  };
  ULONG SystemReserved[1];
  ULONG SpareUlong;
} BPEB, *PBPEB;
```

Comment: Time to fire up the debugger.

Comment: I debugged much so I knew where the crashes happen but don't know why ? as I said the same code works when not using it in a service

Comment: What operations are you doing on `url`?  Maybe you are corrupting the variable in some way?  Maybe it is invalid?

Comment: @dev65 Can you post more info on the crash?

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie the url is a string class contains my php server url and it is printed correctly in the logs file

Comment: @dev65  The crash occurs at the line you stated.  The one thing that is there is `url`.  So far we have yet to see where this variable is initialized, how it get its value, etc.  Also just because you can print doesn't mean that there is no memory corruption going on.

Comment: crashes may happen in the next lines with some strange errors like division by zero and other errors , also happened on curl_easy perform/cleanup

Comment: `pipe_buffer` is not guaranteed to be null-terminated (unless the client sends less than 10000 bytes w/ a null terminator), but the code assumes that it is. You should take `read` into account when using `pipe_buffer`, eg: `ofile << "[*] "; ofile.write(pipe_buffer, read); ofile << endl; ... payload.append(pipe_buffer, read); ...`

Comment: @RemyLebeau I'll try this , but I think this isn't the cause especially the worker process is sending a null terminated buffer , I already used Poco Net in this place and I didn't have any heap corruption , but got integer divided by zero error for one time then I tested again but didn't get the crash again . but it's expensive to use poco for this place only , I should find a solution for this situation or replace curl with poco in entire the code

Comment: @dev65 Why not just use `WinInet` instead?

Comment: seems better , the reason I didn't use winapi from the begin is that I am not familiar with http protocol so I couldn't use raw windsock also I couldn't implement SSL support so I went to curl as I used it in some projects before , today I tried Poco net and going to try cpp-net which seems pretty . I didn't even look at wininet as I thought it's very low level like windsock but I looked at some examples now and I think it will be easy and more lightweight  to use it in this place of the code

Comment: @RemyLebeau WinInet crashed the service immediately , so I went to the documentation and found : " WinINet does not support server implementations. In addition, it should not be used from a service. For server implementations or services use Microsoft Windows HTTP Services (WinHTTP) " so WinHTTP is the required

Comment: also WinHttp crashes immediately on WinHttpOpen !!! I may ask new question about this

Comment: I found a solution for the heap corruption . there is something special in windows services I don't know what is it . using HeapSetInformation with the default process heap and HeapCompatibilityInformation removes the heap corruption . there is still integer divided by zero error , it's coming from getaddrinfo . I think there is another something special for the services causes that

Comment: @dev65 I've written many Windows services, and have NEVER had to resort to using `HeapSetInformation()`, or any other heap management functions, for that matter. And I use `getaddrinfo()` without any errors. So you clearly have a bug somewhere in your code, and your HTTP code just *happens* to be a victim of whatever that bug is corrupting. And if `WinHttpOpen()` is crashing, you are likely not using it correctly.

Comment: @RemyLebeau yes I was fully mistaken the problem wasn't from curl or WinHttpOpen , as I tried using them in some another point before this in the code and no crashes happened so I assume that in a previous job the heap was corrupted and when using any of these functions the corrupt appears . I'll post some of the code and the layout of the service .

Comment: @RemyLebeau I updated the question with some code and found exactly where the errors start

Comment: @RemyLebeau yes I had to use delete[] instead of delete , but this wasn't the problem . I commented the function code line by line to see which line causes errors and put the my answer below

Comment: @RemyLebeau yes I should treat the security of the code seriously

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `GetCommandLineRemote()`, when you allocate `CommandLine.Buffer`, you are over-allocating. `MaximumLength` is expressed in bytes, and `WCHAR` is 2 bytes in size. Your use of `new[]` is allocating 2x more memory than you really need, but that is OK since you are not reading more bytes than you allocate.  You should divide `MaximumLength` by `sizeof(WCHAR)` to avoid over-allocating when using `new WCHAR[]`:

```
CommandLine.Buffer = new WCHAR[(CommandLine.MaximumLength / sizeof(WCHAR)) + 1];
```

However, the `UNICODE_STRING` data you read is not guaranteed to be null terminated, but you are treating it as if it were when constructing the final `wstring`. You should take the `Length` into account (which is also expressed in bytes) instead of relying on a null terminator:

```
wstring wCommandLine(CommandLine.Buffer, CommandLine.Length / sizeof(WCHAR));
```

More importantly, you are freeing `CommandLine.Buffer` with `delete` instead of `delete[]`, so your code has **undefined behavior** from that point onward. Memory allocated with `new` is freed with `delete`. Memory allocated with `new[]` is freed with `delete[]`. You cannot interchange them.

Also, on a side note, in `enum_ids()`, you are leaking the `HANDLE` returned by `CreateToolhelp32Snapshot()`. You need to close it with `CloseHandle()` when you are done using it.

Comment: I'll implement this , I thought UNCODE_STRING::Length includes the null terminate character but from microsoft : "Length : Specifies the length, in bytes, of the string pointed to by the Buffer member, not including the terminating NULL character, if any"

Answer (score 0):

the exactly lines that caused the heap corruption are these :

```
CommandLine.Buffer = new WCHAR[CommandLine.MaximumLength];
result = ReadProcessMemory(hProc, (void*)parameters.CommandLine.Buffer, CommandLine.Buffer, parameters.MaximumLength, 0);
```

the ReadProcessMemory succeeds but causes a heap corruption that appears on using curl functions

changing this line :

```
CommandLine.Buffer = new WCHAR[CommandLine.MaximumLength];
```

to this :

```
CommandLine.Buffer = (wchar_t*)HeapAlloc(GetProcessHeap(), HEAP_ZERO_MEMORY, CommandLine.MaximumLength);
```

then freeing the buffer before returning with HeapFree instead of delete solves the problem

I didn't face any problem like this where ReadProcessMemory  caused such strange errors if it read into a buffer allocated with new

the documentation of the function hasn't anything about this

did anyone face such problem ?

Comment: The original code using `new[]` was not corrupting memory, but it was over-allocating more memory than you needed. I updated my answer to explain that.